# Replacing $x^x$ by $e^{x\cdot\ln(x)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, exponential-function

In which case is it allowed to replace a given real valued function such as $f(x)=x^x$ by the term $e^{x\cdot\ln(x)}$?

To be more specific: What properties must a function have so that it's allowed to replace $a^b$ by an exponential function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*If one only considers real valued functions*, one has that
$$
a^b=e^{b \ln a}
$$ holds *iff* $a>0$. Then one is allowed to write $x^x=e^{x \ln x}$ for any real number $x$ such that $x>0$.

Comment: Well for $b \in \mathbb R$ usually $a^b$ is not even defined for $a < 0$, is it?

Comment: @Ant $(-1)^2$ is well defined. But for *general* $b$, you are right.

Comment: @Bastian Schoettle You are welcome.

Comment: Could you do me a favor and tell me a bit more about the background why this is allowed?

Answer (score 1):

This question is a little bit confusing. 
$$a^x := \exp\left(x \ln a \right)$$
is the *definition* of powers with exponents $x\in \mathbf C$ and $a>0$. Therefore expressions like $x^x$ are *only* for $x>0$ defined.

Comment: Not really. You may consider $(-2)^3$ which is equal to $-8$, we have $-2 \le 0$, $3 \in \mathbb{C}$.